# How do fix this android studio error on mac high sierra?

Tags: android, macos

[image]

I tried googling the problem but no solution for my mac...

Comment: Do you have about 10GB free disk space ?

Comment: yes about 1.55 terabyte

Comment: For debugging purposes, run `emulator -avd  Pixel...` and paste result here

Comment: bash: emulator: command not found ... I am not sure if there's anything else I had to do with the command.

Comment: emulator is in `.../android-sdk/emulator/emulator`. Search with `find android-sdk-direcoty -name emulator`

Comment: MacBook:Slot_Exported $ cd "/Users/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"
MacBook:emulator $ emulator -avd  Pixel
bash: emulator: command not found

Comment: Try `./emulator ...`

Comment: emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel], use -list-avds to see valid list.
HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

Comment: You need to put whole name `Pixel_3a_API_30_x86`

Comment: emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Users/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Comment: emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 1, security: Local
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"
VCPU shutdown request

Comment: Android Emulator  30.4.5 Installed

Comment: I have 30.4.5 as well which works well

Comment: Yeah, I am still getting the error, @Philippe I appreciate your help.